# Email to Register Confirmation Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

The confirmation email is arriving normal at test@hotmail.com. But whenever I click the message appears:'Activation link is invalid!' ever.

Can someone help me?

Views.py

```
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            register_status = register_user(request)
            if register_status != 1:
                messages.error(request, register_status)
                return redirect('register')
            #Register Success
            else:
                user = get_user_model()
                subject = 'Confirm your account'
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('users/acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                from_email = 'myacount@gmail.com'
                to_list = [from_email , 'test@hotmail.com']
                send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                from_email,
                to_list,
                fail_silently=False,
                )
                messages.success(request, 'Please confirm your email')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request, 'users/register.html')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'You are already logged in')
        return redirect('index')


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        print(user)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

tokens.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six



class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>', views.activate, name='activate'),

]
```

registration.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from usersettings.models import UserSettings

from datetime import datetime
User = get_user_model()

def register_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    password2 = request.POST['password2']

    result = check_input(username, email, password, password2)

    if result != 1:
        return result
    else:
        return save_user(username, email, password, password2)


def check_input(username, email, password, password2, test_date):
    if password != password2:
        return 'Passwords do not much'
    else:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            return 'Username is taken'
        else:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return 'Email is taken'
            else:
            # Success
                 return 1

def save_user(username, email, password, password2):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
    user.save()
    UserSettings.objects.create(user=user)
    return 1
```

acc_active_email.html

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

link

```
http://localhost:8000/users/activate/PHByb3BlcnR5IG9iamVjdCBhdCAweDdmMTM4YzdiODMxOD4/5ew-d33b3465e38a871c4c06
```

I tried many fixes but I was unsuccessful. I am new to Django and have also not found anything to fix this problem online.

Can someone help me make this confirmation email work?

Comment: can you share the link

Comment: http://localhost:8000/users/activate/PHByb3BlcnR5IG9iamVjdCBhdCAweDdmMTM4YzdiODMxOD4/5ew-d33b3465e38a871c4c06